# mysql compress order_by values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column order_by whit the values Ex:

```
4,10 ,20 ,80,500,625,712
```

I want modify to:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

If order of 80 is 4 the value will be 4

I want to do something like this :

```
UPDATE tablex SET order_by=ORDER_OF(order_by);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
set @rownum := 0;
UPDATE tablex as t
SET t.order_by = @rownum := @rownum + 1
order by t.order_by
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80ee3/3)

Comment: Thanks but the order is'nt mantain in the fiddle d must be the first

Comment: Now I get you. I updated my answer. The order was not correct