# Condensing MySQL ordered group values

Tags: mysql

This question is an extension of [mysql compress order_by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806813/mysql-compress-order-by-values).

My table has groups of ordered numbers, with undesired gaps.  How can I renumber each of these groups, while keeping the original order?

```
Group   Order   Desired Order
A       1       1
A       3       2
A       6       3
A       7       4

B       2       1
B       3       2
B       8       3

C       1       1
C       7       2
C       8       3
```

Comment: Don't worry about the gaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get the desired order by using a correlated sub query without using and variables

```
select t1.*,
(
  select count(*)
  from demo t2
  where t1.`group` = t2.`group`
  and t1.`order` > t2.`order`
) + 1 desiredorder
from demo t1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af2d3/4)

Or to update same table with your desired order you can use below query

```
update demo a
join (select t1.*,(
        select count(*)
        from demo t2
        where t1.`group` = t2.`group`
        and t1.`order` > t2.`order`
        ) + 1 desiredorder
      from demo t1
) b on a.`group` = b.`group`
    and a.`order` = b.`order`
set a.`order` = b.desiredorder
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ffaf65/1)

> Note make sure to add an index on group and order column for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to store the previous value of `group` and another one for the `desiredorder`. Essentially this is a mimic of a Window Function ROW_NUMBER which MySql doesn't support.

I renamed the columns as `group=col1, order=col2`

```
select col1,
       col2,
       neworder
from (
  select t.col1,
         t.col2,
         case when @prev=t.col1 then @id:=@id+1 else @id:=1 end as neworder,
         @prev:=t.col1
    from (select @prev:=null, @id:=0) a,
         toorder t
   order by t.col1
) a
```

See it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d8528/2

The external query is only needed if you want to pull out only those three columns.